# Get deployed .aspx page in feature receiver to add WebPart

Tags: 2010, web-part, deployment, feature-receiver

I have a SharePoint solution which deploys an `aspx` page in a custom folder in the `Layouts` folder. I need to get this page in the `Feature Event Receiver` so I can add to it a `WebPart`.

In the `FeatureActivated` method when I am trying to use this code:

```
SPFile file = web.GetFile("_layouts/My Folder/MyPage.aspx");
```

This code returns a `File not found exception`.

How can I get a reference to this page? Is this error occuring because the page has not been deployed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for `Spongeroberto Squarepantalones` and `SPArchaeologist` help, I did the following:

1. I created a `Module` in my SharePoint Solution and added to it an `aspx` page.
2. In this `aspx` page I added an `WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager` and a  `WebPartPages:WebPartZone`.
3. I edited the `Elements.xml` file in the module to deploy the page in a `Document Library`. (I need to access this page from a specified site only).
4. In the `FeatureActivated` method in the `Feature Event Receiver` I added code to create a `WebPart`, get this page as an `SPFile` and used an `SPLimitedWebPartManager` to add my created `WebPart`. (I did this and had not created a `WepPart` in the `aspx` page directly because the WebPart displays SharePoint items from a `Document Library` and use a SharePoint `View` that are deployed in the same solution, so their GUID allways change).

Comment: Moussa, you can also accept your own answer if needed. That way, other people will know that your question contains an answer that resolved your problem - this can help people searching. No need to do that right now, but know it is an option.

Comment: Thank you SPArchaeologist I will, but I need 2 days to be able to accept my own answer.

Comment: Urgh, sorry, I was thinking they removed that limit when the "answer your question" option was implemented in questions. Seems it is **not** the case. My bad, disregard that comment

Answer (score 0):

Items are deployed *before* the event receiver. The problem is you're trying to read a hive file. That's not gonna work with the SPWeb.GetFile method. That method is meant for files that are stored in that web.

You can still read the file, however. I needed to do the same and wrote a method like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// get the proper path to the hive
/// </summary>
private static string GetUtilPath(string path)
{
    return SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath(@"TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyModule\" + path);
}

/// <summary>
/// Access a file in the SharePoint hive
/// </summary>    
/// <param name="path">the path relative to the layouts folder</param>   
private static byte[] GetHiveFile(string path)
{
    string utilPath = GetUtilPath(path);
    using(FileStream fs = new FileStream(utilPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
        long numbytes = new FileInfo(utilPath).Length;
        return br.ReadBytes((int)numbytes);
    }                                   
}
```

Then you can read a file from the hive like this:

```
byte[] file = GetHiveFile(@"myfolder\myfile.txt");
```

Comment: Thanks for this method. If I use it how can I create an SPFile object? Because I need an SPFile to be able to add a WebPart to the page. Or is there another way?

Comment: If you want to add a web part to that specific page, I guess you would be better off copying the hive file to a document library on your web. You can use the byte[] to do that. Here's how you would add it to the site pages library: SPFolder sitePages = web.Lists["Site Pages"].RootFolder; sitePages.Files.Add("mypage.aspx", file);

Comment: +1 for pointing me in the right direction. Thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on other answers (see [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/1615/5173) or  [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/a879b0c4-3d3b-462e-9db9-84f09df0ed79)) SPFile.GetFile(string) cannot be used to get hold of a "SPFile" in the _layout folder.
There are other way to read the page (like some answer suggested), but in the end you would just obtain a stream/bytearray or such - you are trying to add a web part, so I fear that wouldn't really help. That is because as far as SharePoint is concerned, _layout is a virtual IIS folder, and file inside it AREN'T seen as SPfile.

That said, adding a web part to an application page as far as I known isn't even supported: if you try to add a web part zone with a web part inside you should receive an error similar to "“Unknown server tag WebPartZone" (see [this blog](http://www.sharepointwithattitude.com/archives/190) or [this answer from Dave](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointcustomizationlegacy/thread/5c34e7f0-cf63-4463-a9e3-980ca49dc3f7)). Web part on application page are possible only if used as standard web control (and even there there are some issues with caching and such).

If you *have to*, your best bet seems to be opening the file programmatically like a text file and then adding the required tags manually - you won't be able to use the web part manager. Anyway, I would try and see if I can redeploy that page to a page library or such and transform it to a standard publishing page.

Comment: I programmatically added web parts to aspx pages using web part manager. This does require you to copy the page to a web first, and to add web part zones beforehand.

Comment: And that's the point. If you copy it to the web, it is not an application page anymore (or at last not strictly talking). Since at that point you would lose one of the main point of using a _layout page (-> the page is the same for all web site), why keep it in the layout folder at all? That said, if you *don't have control* of the page original location AND is *acceptable to customize it on a web site basis* your solution should work without problem.

Comment: Btw, I was more point at explaining WHY you can't use the SPFile object (never intended to say that your solution is wrong). Your solution provide a valid alternative for customizing the page, but all depends on what is acceptable for the user.